# How to redirect stdin/stdout/stderr in Visual Studio to a Visual Studio window when debugging a console application?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

I am writing a cross-platform application in C++ using Visual Studio.

My project type is the most basic one "Win32 console application".

I admit it, I haven't mastered all bits of windows software development, but there seems to be a clear pattern:

When you run an application from a CMD session, by default, Windows connects the app's default stdin/stdout/stderr with this CMD session.
(I.e. when you type 'dir' in a cmd session, it doesn't fire up a new cmd window.)

This is, however, not the case when running an application from VS. That is, when I press F5, it fires up a new console window, runs my console app inside this window and connects stdin/stdout/stderr with this console window.

What I want is instead to connect stdin/stdout/stderr with a sub-window inside the Visual Studio itself. (Akin to an "Immediate" window.)
Then I won't have to switch back and forth between VS and CMD.

Clearly, there should be some mechanisms to achieve that, since from an ordinary command prompt I could do something like:

```
a.exe 1>stdout.txt 2>stderr.txt <stdin.txt
```

I'd like Visual Studio to do something like that when running my application, but instead of files, connect the streams to a sub-window in VS.

The principal thing here is that this should be done without any modifications to the application code itself, because it must be completely independent of the development environment and/or platform.
(That's why I didn't use one of the many solutions found on stackoverflow -- they all are based on some adaptation of the application code.)

Comment: Visual Studio is not a CMD session so I don't get why this is surprising! You appear to understand how shells work. VS needs to launch a shell to run your program. Anyway, it's technically possible to connect that TTY's I/O pipes to something inside VS but I don't know whether VS has implemented that feature. Doubt it tbh. Why do you think you need this? Why can't you use the IDE in the same manner as everyone else?

Comment: *"when you type 'dir' in a cmd session, it doesn't fire up a new cmd window"* - The *dir* command is implemented by the command interpreter. It is not a standalone application.

Comment: This would potentially make the program behave differently, which is not the sort of thing you want in a debugger.

Comment: @HarryJohnston The thing is, I am actually not going to run this binary in a console window. I am going to only use it as a backend with its stdin/stdout piped to a caller program. (Like a GUI frontend calling a backend.)

Comment: For the record, that's not usually the best way to implement a backend in Windows.  Consider making it a DLL instead.  At any rate, there's no direct way to do what you're asking, and even if there were, you'd still be on the hook to make sure the frontend application behaved exactly the same way as Visual Studio.  Might be best to run the backend via your frontend and connect the debugger to it manually.  (Actually I think you can automate the process, but I'm not sure of the details.)

Comment: Visual Studio does have a plugin API, of course, so it *might* be possible to write a plugin to do this.  However, I've never used the API myself, so I don't know what it is or isn't capable of.